# 小手先で済ませるよりは結局早く終わるだろうと、分解しつつ片っ端から手をつけていったら、完全にバラしてまた組み直すような真似をしていた

Tags: meaning

While taking a look at his bicycle the protagonist said.

> つい気になった部分を、**小手先で済ませるよりは結局早く終わるだろうと、分解しつつ片っ端から手をつけていったら、完全にバラしてまた組み直すような真似をしていた。**

> Regarding the parts I got interest in, thinking it's better to finish it early rather than to finish it superficially, While I was dissembling I started tampering with it and I dissembled it and reassembled it.

I am having trouble understanding pretty much the entire sentence. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

小手先で済ませるよりは結局早く終わるだろうと: thinking it will eventually be finished earlier than to settle it down superficially

- "it's better to finish it early" would be 早く終わらせるべき

分解しつつ片っ端から手をつけていったら: as I dissemble**d** it and <s>take</s> took every single piece in sight

- したら = when I do, していったら = as I do

完全にバラしてまた組み直すような真似をしていた: I found myself doing something like thoroughly dissembling and reassembling it again.

- まね basically means mimicking but here it's used to express how pointless the work was, though he was actually doing it.

Edit: ～ていく means

1. do something somewhere and left there e.g. 食べていこう: let's eat it before we go
2. the action evolves to the direction away from the point-of-view e.g. 押していけ: push forward
3. something gradually changes or result of a recursive action accumulates e.g. 無数の星が消えていく: countless stars vanish<s>es</s> one after another

In this case, it's used in the third sense and していったら instead of simple したら means he recognized himself in the course of the work, not so much as he worked, then recognized.

Comment: 「～ていった」をstartと訳したのかもしれません